# powertoys and Alt-space

Tags: windows-11, powertoys

When powertoys is running Alt-space is opening a search window.
I am afraid I activated this accidengtally (not sure, perhaps it's normally with powertoys).

How can I deactivate this? I'd like to have the default behavior again which is now only available when powertoys is not running.

Comment: Alt+Space is suppose to “Open the shortcut menu for the active window.” if a search menu is being displayed you will have to identify if PowerToys is the active program. If you dislike that functionality you should kill PowerToys

Comment: Note that alt-shift-space still brings up the window resize, etc menu. Good luck restoring the old binding, but alt-shift-space is available if ever sitting at someone else's PC.

Comment: @tewha Where is this shortcut described? I would expect the PowerToys documentation to describe this change prominently but I am unable to find any official information at all :( --- BTW I noticed that Win+Alt+Space works too.

Comment: No idea, but I think you're being a little generous in expecting documentation around PowerToys. It's been run as a glorious hack-a-thon. I'm pretty sure alt-shift-space works even without PowerToys, it's just the shortcut that continues to work *with* PowerToys.

Answer (score 4):

Grrmmll,
For the case you have the same problem: the feature is PowerToys Run.
You can enable / disable it there or define another shortcut.